# What physical laws would need to change?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, multiverse, laws-of-physics, white-holes

My fictional worlds reside in a multiverse. More specifically, they reside in a universe within that multiverse that is very similar to ours.

But here are some big differences:

1. White holes are in equilibrium with black holes
   [image]

This is the complete penrose diagram for an eternal black hole with 0 charge or rotation. It doesn't quite describe what I mean by white holes in equilibrium with black holes because it is across time, not space.

But for every black hole in the multiverse, there is a white hole it is connected to via the singularity. This means there must be negative gravity in the white hole. Or in Einsteinian terms, space-time curvature must be negative in the white hole. This means the white hole has the negative of the mass of the black hole.

But just because the multiverse has this equilibrium does not mean that a given universe will also have this equilibrium. Some have more black holes, some have more white holes, some have equal numbers, and sometimes the white hole forms a totally new universe.

In this case, black holes would correspond to dark matter and white holes to dark energy in the sense that white holes cause expansion and the more white holes, the faster it expands. Black holes due to general relativity would slow down this expansion.

2. All universes are cyclic
   [image]

White holes forming new universes implies that every universe within the multiverse must be cyclic. In other words, every universe must collapse to infinite density via gravity. This requires that there is dark matter and dark energy and more specifically that dark matter must be synthesized in some way.

Maybe virtual particles having a chance to turn into gravitons(gravity carrying particles) and that chance being way higher in areas of dark matter. This way, an observer would notice an increase in dark matter and thus gravity. More dark matter = higher chance of graviton formation = even more gravity -> gravitational collapse of universe -> Another big bang.

This means that there must be quantum spacetime.

**But with these white holes and cyclic universes as I have written, what physical laws would need to change and how? Would there need to be a quantum relativity?**

Comment: More appropriate to Worldbuilding SE.  There are science and hard-science tags on Worldbuilding that are probably relevant to your question.

Comment: Virtual particles are an artifact of quantum field theory, which is a relativistic quantum theory. So, in some sense, you definitely require QFT or at least a form of Relativistic Quantum Mechanics. As for the rest, this is a big question with lots of possibilities. We would require full blown mathematical calculations to see the predictions. Let's see what pops up.

Comment: @StephenG We are yet to answer what constitutes dark matter and dark energy. If what the OP suggests turns out to be mathematically stable, we can actually tinker with it ti see if it applies to our universe ( although I guess, hefty assumptions like - natural black and white holes arising out of nowhere in the quantum foam due to uncertainties- would be required, yet it might be plausible.) I don't know if this is actually on-topic for this site ( we don't actually answer non-mainstream physics ), yet looks like a good question to me.